# Homotopy theory of subcatogory of cofibrant objects?

Tags: homotopy-theory, model-categories

Let $(C,\mathcal{W},\mathcal{C},\mathcal{F})$ be a model category. The homotopy category is defined as the localization of category $C$ with respect to $\mathcal{W}$, denoted by $C[\mathcal{W}^{-1}]$ or $HoC$. Let $\mathcal{C}_c$ denote the full subcatogory of cofibrant objects of $C$.

And then I saw the expression $HoC_c$, meaning the homotopy category of $C_c$? But $\mathcal{W}$ is not contained in $Mor(C_c)$, right? I am really annoyed by this $HoC_c$ thing. Can anyone explain?

Comment: You invert the weak equivalences that are in the (sub)category. Easy.

Comment: @ZhenLin you mean $HoC_c = C_c[\mathcal{W'}^{-1}] $ where $\mathcal{W'}$ IS part of  $\mathcal{W}$ which contained in $Mor(C_c)$?

Comment: Yes. That's what I said.

Comment: thank you very much.@ZhenLin